# Extract subarray of each chunk and convert to string

Tags: php, arrays, string

My code is as the following:

```
$text = "john1,steven2,lex66,e1esa2,444e3, and so forth[...]"; // up to about 180 entries
$arrayChunk = array_chunk(explode(',', $text), 39); // which leaves me with 5 chunks

foreach ($arrayChunk as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
            $string = $subvalue;
        }
        echo $string; // echo all the subvalues (but only echos the first)
    }
}
```

So, I end up with 5 chunks, and I need foreach to echo all the subvalues of the array like this:

```
john1,steven2,[...]
doe4,joe7,[...]
svend2,ole5[...]
olga7,jan3[...]
leila9,aija9[...]
```

instead of just

```
john1
doe4
svend2
olga7
leila9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using:

```
 $string = $subvalue;
```

And then only outputting one. If you want to echo all, use implode:

```
 foreach ($arrayChunk as $key => $value)
    {
            if (is_array($value))
            {
                 echo implode(', ', $value) . "<br>";
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add`echo implode(', ', $value);`
2. Add `echo "<br>";` for line break

   ```
   foreach ($arrayChunk as $key => $value)
           {
                   if (is_array($value))
                   {

                        echo implode(', ', $value);
                        echo "<br>";
                   }
           }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `explode()`, `array_chunk()`, `foreach()`, `is_array()`, `implode()`, I recommend a more direct regex approach.

My method splits your string on the 39th comma -- no extra handling, simple.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AJe72))

```
$text="a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,10,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,20,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,30,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,40,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,50";
$groups=preg_split('/(?:[^,]+\K,){39}/',$text);
foreach($groups as $group){
    echo "$group\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,10,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,20,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,30,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
40,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,50
```

The pattern will match the values followed by a comma 39-times and restart the fullstring match (using `\K`) on the trailing comma -- this restart means that there will be no trailing comma on any of the strings in `$groups`.

Here is a [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f41Ucg/1).